# Display my game over text for 2 seconds before going to my other code

Tags: java, pause

I've tried to use Thread.sleep() but it pauses the program entirely before displaying game over very briefly. I've also tried to display the game over text before Thread.sleep() but I can't see it. Below is what I'm currently using.

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(2000);//pause for 2 seconds
    //display gameover
    gr.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    gr.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
    gr.drawString("Game Over", 550, 300);
}
catch(InterruptedException e){
}
```

Comment: Are you using Swing? You may want to look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), Swing is not thread safe and the UI should only be modified from within the context

Comment: I don't understand, what you're trying to do. Can you clarify? Are you trying to display "Game Over" for 2 seconds and then execute code or what?

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer` (at a guess) - see [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details. See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for a basic overview as to why your current approach doesn't work

Comment: @Kaimson Yes, I am trying to display "Game Over" for 2 seconds, then execute other code which is to restart my game (which I've already done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a boolean `showText` for example, and then use it to determine, if you want to show text.

```
public void runGameLogic() {
    showText = true;
    Timer t = new Timer(2000, (action) -> {
        showText = false;
    });
    t.setRepeats(false);
    t.start();
}

public void render() {
    if (showText) {
        gr.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        gr.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
        gr.drawString("Game Over", 550, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: My "Game Over" text is inside a paintComponent method, so I tried to run it from outside of it and ran

paintComponent.gr.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paintComponent.gr.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
paintComponent.gr.drawString("Game Over", 550, 300);

but it doesn't seem to work, I'm also confused about what the (action) thing you wrote is.

Comment: I'm using a lambda expression from Java 8 to shorten ActionListener to (action), thats what that arrow "->" is. Try to put the render() part into your paintComponent() method.

Comment: It gave me a "illegal start of expression" error probably because it's inside a for loop and I called the runGame Logic method with "runGameLogic();" before the render method but doesn't work either :(

Comment: I can't help you, if you don't provide more information. Please post your paintMethod() and runGameLogic() method to pastebin.com

Comment: Ok, I just made it, here's the link, https://pastebin.com/7YWmk3H2

Comment: There are a few things, that you don't understand. 1. my runGameLogic(); method should be called, when the player dies, for example and NOT in the render. 2. Remove the render(); call in my runGameLogic(); method. 3. Move the public void render() ... outside of your paintComponent() method and call it using "render();"

Comment: But if I move public void render() outside of the paintComponent I can't use stuff like gr.drawString("Game Over", 550, 300); I've tried paintComponent.gr.drawString("Game Over", 550, 300); to get info from paintCompenent but it doesn't work

Comment: You can add to public void render(); a parameter, like so: public void render(Graphics gr); and then call it like so: render(gr)